# Redirect sub domain to sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect the the subdomain to subdirectory but not working. Here is my efforts.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^name\.site_url
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site_url/name/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your_domain/sub/$1 [R,L]
```

Instead sub in RewriteCond and RewriteRule you can place whatever you want

Btw, `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.my\.domain$` also works for me. So, check your site url. Or give more info (at least, what happened in apache error.log).